# GnuPG and TPM : IPC error

Tags: gnupg, tpm

Ι installed the latest version of gpg in manjaro OS:

```
$lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    n/a
Distributor ID: ManjaroLinux
Description:    Manjaro Linux
Release:    22.0.4
Codename:   Sikaris
```

and test `tpm` in `gpg`. I generate an `RSA` key and then

```
$gpg --edit-key xxx.com
```

and then

```
gpg> keytotpm 
Really move the primary key? (y/N) y
gpg: error from TPM: Unknown IPC command
```

Any idea what it may be wrong here?

The user belongs to `tss group` as the documentation of gpg suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the problem resolved as follows :

Since I wanted [TPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) (Trusted Platform Module) support, I needed a `gpg` version at least 2.3. Since, the communication of TPM chip with gpg is not implemented in versions <2.3. Thus, I installed 2.3.2 (and I also tested for 2.4.0). The problem I described in my post finally it was that the system loads `gpg-agent` from `/usr/bin`, but the new version of `gpg-agent` was in the path `/usr/local/bin/`
So, the gpg version I used was different from the gpg-agent version that the system  used.

Initially, in order not to break anything first I did (but it is not necessary) :

```
$sudo mv /usr/bin/gpg-agent /usr/bin/gpg-agent-old
```

and then

```
$sudo cp /usr/local/bin/gpg-agent /usr/bin/gpg-agent
```

In this way we solved the problem.

However, another problem appeared when I executed

`$gpg --edit-key xxx.com`  and then

`>keytotpm`

It could not find the `pinetry`.  I created in `/home/.gnupg` directory the file `gpg-agent.conf` and I added the line

`pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-curses`

That's it.